# mysql merge data assign same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a DB table that is storing data from two separate csv import files. So what I want to do is change the dataId field so the records can be merged into one row.

so the records where the dataId=102 must be changed to be dataId=122 based on the Dealer Code = DC10000 as everything is matched against this column.

How can I do this with a single select and update query

[image]

Thanks in advance

Danny Younes

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Both sample data and the expected result.) Don't forget to show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Your question is so unclear. please do some more efforts to make a question good looking and clear. Simple update not working for your case? WHY?

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
UPDATE table SET dataId=dataId+20 WHERE (SELECT * FROM table WHERE dataId=102 AND ealer Code = DC10000 )
```

sub query fetches only record which has `dataid`(102) & `seller code`(DC10000),

main query update those records `dataid` with +20 which gives `dataid=122`

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation would help a lot in understanding the method you've used and how it works.